# What does this string format mean in C++?

Tags: c++, dll, formatting, reuters

Ok this might be one of the not-so-smartest questions I have asked in awhile. Sadly, google led me to no answer (neither did stack).

In a C++ dll file, i have this line:

`pSDB->setString("Logger\\AppLogger\\fileLoggerFilename", "rfa.{P}.log")`

I, for the life of me, cannot find out what the {P} accurately represents. In the directory, I will get logs that look like: 'rfa.6702.log', 'rfa.6829.log', or 'rfa.7024.log'.

I notice they keep increasing. Does this legitimately mean anything in C++, or just a parameter set in the code?

EDIT:

This code is dealing with Reuters connections. The `pSDB` is:

"rfa::config::StagingConfigDatabase *ConnectionManager"

Comment: It's probably a form of generating a unique number, though why it wouldn't just go up by one doesn't make much sense with that.

Comment: This was my guess as well. I guess I'm wondering how the number is determined.

Comment: Regarding your edit, you'll need to read the documentation for whatever type `StagingConfigDatabase` is.

Comment: Yea Reuters is notorious for not having that great documentation, especially considering this is a really old API. Don't have access to any form of documentation.

Comment: seeing the log names this can be the PID

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01615.0510/doc/html/cgo1316096420433.html):

> The Reuters library replaces the {p} string in the default file name
>   with the UNIX Process ID when it creates the log file.

Comment: That fits quite well. Good find.

Comment: Dude, I love you. EXCELLENT find.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with C++. C++ will never look inside your strings. Same is true for "%d" in printf. It is all a matter of what printf() is doing.

To answer your question, you need to refer to the actual object parsing your string.

Answer (score 2):

This is not standard C++. It is defined in what looks like may be a logger library. You should look at the documentation for this parcitular library to find out `{P}` means. In particular, look at the docs for the `setString()` method in whatever class you used to declare `pSDB`.